# laravel databse seed pivot table

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, laravel-seeding

I've this tables in my Laravel app:
Users
Books
Categories
book_category
Authors
author_book

---

im seeding my table wth this code:

```
factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function ($user) {
    $user->books()
        ->create(factory(App\Book::class)->make()->toArray())
        ->category()
        ->attach([1,2]);
 });
```

How can I add author too this code for seed?
Is there another way?

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to accomplish.  You create a book for every user and attach the same two categories for every book.    Is there a reason you can't run the attach the same way for the authors?

Comment: thanks Devon, but in the following this code how i attach author? ->author()->attach([1,2])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to add a book to every user. Try creating a new factory for books and then attach `$user` to your `$book`.

```
factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function ($user) {
    $book = factory(App\Book::class)->create();
    $user->books()->attach($book);
});
```